# WPF Tag button binding with ConverterParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a `Button` whose `Tag` depends on a boolean variable.
I implemented the Binding as follow:

```
Tag="{Binding LiveInProgress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
      Converter={StaticResource BoolToPathConverter}, Mode=OneWay, 
      ConverterParameter=cross.svg|play.svg}"
```

Where the `Converter` is the following:

```
public class BoolToPathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var parameterString = parameter as string;
            if (parameterString.IsNullOrEmpty()) return "";

            var parameters = parameterString.Split(new char[]{ '|'});
            if ((bool) value)
                return parameters[0];

            return parameters[1];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can't see any Tag. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: How are you expecting to "see a Tag"?

Comment: I expected to see the image obtained  by the Converter. The xaml code was right but I did a very stupid error on the Converter: I didn't specify the path where the icons are.

Comment: Then you would also need a Style (or something else) to actually visualize the Tag. A Button doesn't do that by default.